# Retina tells me I do not have permission to scan a range. I have full permissions. Why?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners

I am using Retina via BeyondInsight 5.2.0.410 to scan my network.

Occasionally, I get the error message "You do not have the required permissions to scan the entered range" which doesn't make sense because within BeyondInsight my account has every permission.

Any pointers on where to look?

Comment: You could try speaking to the retina support folks if this causes problems. It is off topic here.

Comment: How is a question about a security tool off-topic? It's right in the list of on-topic subjects in the help center.

Comment: The question is not about security, it is about the configuration of a particular tool - which is generally much better served on the support forums for that tool.

Comment: Can you give an example of a question about a "security tool" which would pass your test? It seems awfully arbitrary to me. We're free to ask navel-gazey questions about security, but as soon as we talk about how to use a security tool, it's off-topic?

Comment: The problem with the question is that it is directly a technical support question, and we don't want to become the dumping ground of tech support for software, even security software. Interpreting results, questions about applying tools, ways to improve use of a tool MAY be on topic, though.

Comment: In addition to schroeder's point, please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19487/154443

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the fine manual, I found this tidbit about permissions:

> Manual Range Entry
>   Allows the user to manually enter ranges for Scans
>   and Deployments rather than being restricted to Smart Groups. *The
>   specified ranges must be within the selected Smart Group.*

[Emphasis mine]

On a hunch, I tried this:

1. Go back to the Assets tab
2. Choose "All Assets"
3. Try running my scan again, manually specifying a range like I did the first time.

And it worked!

The problem is that retina still confines your scan to the Smart Group you chose in the Assets tab even when you choose to scan a single IP address or IP Range.

[image: BeyondInsight Retina user interface. Note that the selected smart group can cause permission errors when you manually specify scan IPs]

In summary:

**To avoid a permissions problem when manually entering an IP or IP range to scan, first choose the All Assets Smart Group.**